# Cómo guardar la fecha del DateTimePicker en Sql? - VB

Tags: sql, vba

Estoy intentando guardar la fecha y hora con am o pm según seleccione el usuario, en una base de datos de **SQL** y el campo donde se guarda es de tipo **DateTime**, estoy guardando la fecha y hora con un **DateTimePicker** desde viasul basic..

Si guarda la fecha y la hora pero no guarda **am** o **pm** 
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 Dim fecha = DateTest.Value
        Dim fe As String
        fe = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        Dim Conexion As String
        Conexion = "Data Source=GDJF04973;Initial Catalog=Cap_Pruebas;User ID=f5;Password=f5report"
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection
        cn.ConnectionString = Conexion
        Dim adaptador As New SqlCommand("insert into Debug_Test values(" & TestID.Text & ",'" & TestUser.Text & "','" & SerialNumber.Text & "'," & Shift.Text & ",'" & fe & "','" & DebugTest.Text & "','" & FailureMode_T.Text & "','" & TestStation_T.Text & "','" & Localidad_T.Text & "','" & SubFamily_T.Text & "','" & Operador_T.Text & "','" & ErrorOperador_T.Text & "','" & Acciones_T.Text & "')", cn)
        cn.Open()
```

El **DateTimePicker** tiene el formato **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt** para que pueda ver am o pm.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: en sql no se guarda AM o PM, guarda la hora en formato 24 horas, o sea despues de las 12:59:59 sera 13:00:00 considerandose 13 PM

Comment: si lo quieres guardar como comentas, no uses datetime en sql, mejor usa un campo varchar

Comment: En `SQL` verás la fecha en formato 24 Horas, no te mostrará `a.m.` o `p.m.`. Puedes salvar la fecha con el siguiente formato: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` fijate que las `HH` están en mayúsculas, esto indica que es formato 24 horas, y cuando la quieras mostrar en tu `DateTimePicker` si la conviertes el formato que muestras en la pregunta...

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Lo are como tu dices.